# MySQL slave database stopped replication."Last_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'sen'' on query. Default"

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, database-cluster

the master:

[image: Markdown]
[image: Markdown]

the slave:

[image: Markdown]
[image: Markdown]

## Current Environment

```
sen@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sen@ubuntu:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

## Current Status

**Master, 3306:**

my.cnf : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmelrjhrp6wn2oj/my_3306.cnf?dl=0

show processlist:
Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated

[image: Markdown]

```
sen@ubuntu:/data/3306$ sudo /application/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000007
[sudo] password for sen:
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
# #161106 10:39:40 server id 1  end_log_pos 107   Start: binlog v 4, server
# v 5.5.32-log created 161106 10:39:40 at startup
# # Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.
# ROLLBACK/*!*/;
# BINLOG '
# 7JceWA8BAAAAZwAAAGsAAAABAAQANS41LjMyLWxvZwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
# AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADslx5YEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAVAAEGggAAAAICAgCAA==
# '/*!*/;
# DELIMITER ;
# # End of log file
# ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
# /*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
# /*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
#
```

**Slave,3307:**

my.cnf : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5t6mruzuo3wo1l7/my_3307.cnf?dl=0

show processlist: Waiting for master to send event

```
mysql> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.80.2
                  Master_User: rep
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000007
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 107
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000011
                Relay_Log_Pos: 253
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1049
                   Last_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'sen'' on query. Default
database: 'sen'. Query: 'create table t(id int(11), primary key(id))'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 107
              Relay_Log_Space: 2873
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1049
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'sen'' on query. Default
database: 'sen'. Query: 'create table t(id int(11), primary key(id))'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

the relay bin log:

```
sen@ubuntu:/data/3307$ sudo /application/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog relay-bin.000020
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
# #161106 17:00:43 server id 2  end_log_pos 107   Start: binlog v 4, server
# v 5.5.32 created 161106 17:00:43
# BINLOG '
# O/EeWA8CAAAAZwAAAGsAAAAAAAQANS41LjMyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
# AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAVAAEGggAAAAICAgCAA==
# '/*!*/;
# # at 107
# #700101  8:00:00 server id 1  end_log_pos 0     Rotate to mysql-bin.000007
# pos: 107
# # at 150
# #161106 10:39:40 server id 1  end_log_pos 0     Start: binlog v 4, server
# v 5.5.32-log created 161106 10:39:40
# BINLOG '
# 7JceWA8BAAAAZwAAAAAAAAAAAAQANS41LjMyLWxvZwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
# AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAVAAEGggAAAAICAgCAA==
# '/*!*/;
# DELIMITER ;
# # End of log file
# ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
# /*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
# /*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
#
```

the error log:

```
$ less -R mysql_3307.err
161105 19:39:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
161105 19:39:05 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 1601853
161105 19:39:05 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
161105 19:39:05 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
161105 19:39:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
161105 19:39:05 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@ubuntu' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
161105 19:39:05 [Warning] 'user' entry '@ubuntu' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
161105 19:39:05 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ubuntu' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
161105 19:39:05 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000003' at position 107, relay log '/data/3307/relay-bin.000011' position: 253
161105 19:39:05 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'rep@192.168.80.2:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2003
161105 19:39:05 [ERROR] Slave SQL: Error 'Unknown database 'sen'' on query. Default database: 'sen'. Query: 'create table t(id int(11), primary key(id))', Error_code: 1049
161105 19:39:05 [Warning] Slave: Unknown database 'sen' Error_code: 1049
161105 19:39:05 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000003' position 107
161105 19:39:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
161105 19:39:05 [Note] /application/mysql-5.5.32/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.5.32'  socket: '/data/3307/mysql.sock'  port: 3307  Source distribution
161105 19:40:05 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master  'rep@192.168.80.2:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000004' at position 317
```

**I have searched by google, found**

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19344
[image: Markdown]

**I have done**

1.
restart the two mysql process 3306 and 3307

2.
on slave database:
stop slave;
start slave;

But it doesn't work.(mei shen me luan yong)

Please do me a favor!
tks.

by sen.

Comment: Mate, You don't seem to have database "sen" in Master itself. then how will it replicate it?

Comment: But, normally, isn't it create the "sen" db automatically in the slave?Looked like it was fine before.

Comment: you have to create it. actually you are going to create it only once , right? then probably they could have created it before replication

Comment: Um,okay, think you.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar problem. Long story short if you start replication from zero meaning that you do not have any data on Master or Slave you probably would not see this error.

The problem occurs when you want to start replication but MASTER already has some data(scheme/table) which I suppose you expect to be replicated.
Then you should dump those schemes/tables, import on slave and then start replication.

A good starting point for troubleshooting would be this select - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr3zL.jpg) `select * from performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker\G`
Pay attention to the message `LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 725; Error executing row event: 'Unknown database 'sql_invoicing''`
It basically says you want me to build a roof (start replication) but you do not have walls (database sql_invoicing not created). In this case, I have just created a database(on Slave) and that solves my problem.